# "Error opening terminal: unknown." in Guake since updating to Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

After updating to Ubuntu 10.10, I get an error in Guake.

"Error opening terminal: unknown."

It happens when I try open nano, pico and some other programs. They work normally in the normal terminal.

Any ideas why this is happening or is it happening to anyone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bug in vte](http://guake.org/ticket/249). a fix is impending.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a temporary solution for the problem:
http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/10/11/solved-term-environment-variable-not-set-in-guake/